# saveToEs (elastic search-spark) adding job but not starting

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm trying to save some documents to Elasticsearch:

```
newStream.foreach(rdd => rdd.saveToEs(elasticResource))
```

With the settings for the SparkConf:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]")
.setAppName("RabbitIngestor")
.set("es.nodes", "localhost")
.set("es.port", "9200")
.set("es.index.auto.create", "true")
.set("es.nodes.discovery", "false")
.set("es.batch.size.entries", "0")
val elasticResource = "data/product"
```

And the context:

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(1))
```

But the job is getting nowhere, just adds the job but doesn't start it.

```
15/08/13 17:43:53 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1439484233000 ms
15/08/13 17:43:54 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1439484234000 ms
15/08/13 17:43:55 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1439484235000 ms
```

I thought this had something to do with the batch size (but I'm setting it to 1). Also, its creating the index, if its not there.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**: Eventually I get this error and one doc gets written:

```
15/08/13 18:26:03 ERROR NetworkClient: Node [Operation timed out] failed (172.17.0.28:9200); selected next node [localhost:9200]
```

Still, don't know where it's getting that address instead of the correct one (localhost)

Comment: I am also facing same issue ..can u plz help me out if u solved this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end the problem was that I was running Elasticsearch inside docker, and after the initial handshake through localhost it tried to talk to the nodes directly. So it's a port forwarding issue with Docker.

Comment: I know it's been some time, but could you elaborate on your answer? I'm facing a similar issue and it would be fantastic if you could add some context.

Answer (score 0):

Please run the following query on your SENSE ui
GET _search
{"query":{"match_all":{}}}

And check the count of records.
Is it 0?

Comment: why question in answer?

Comment: @manetsus Sometimes a question is the solution (this is more like instructions to follow and the last instruction is a check)